# Textbox missing when no data in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

I have an input that will display data in model. There supposed to be 2 ways to access this form. Either by entering ID no at the form before, so
the name displayed here, or without entering ID no, which means it is only a blank textbox. I successully retrieved the value from model where the
value is displayed inside the textbox. The problem is when the form is access without model. Textbox are not shown. It only displayed the label.
I am not sure why but i think it is maybe because the input value are assign to model. All i need is a textbox so user can input the data.

```
<div Class="form-group">
    <Label Class="control-label col-md-4">Appointment Start</Label>
    <div Class="col-sm-8">
        @For Each Item In Model
            @<input type="text" name="name" Class="form-control" value="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) Item.name)">
        Next
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` method. And it needs to be inside a `for` loop - you code wont bind to your model when your submit.

Comment: I do it like this `@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) Item.name)` but it doesnt work